# appending to all values in a javascript arrary

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have an array of strings like this:

```
originalArray = ["some value", "another value", "and another"]
```

How would you add to both the beginning and end of each string so it looks like this:

```
finalArray = ["FIRST some value LAST", "FIRST another value LAST", "FIRST and another LAST"]
```

(Obviously I could use a loop but I'd think there's a more efficient method)

Answer (score 6):

### Use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array. ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

For example,

```
var originalArray = ["some value", "another value", "and another"];

var fixedArray = originalArray.map(function(item){
        return "FIRST " + item + " LAST";
    });
```

result

```
["FIRST some value LAST", "FIRST another value LAST", "FIRST and another LAST"]
```